# Need to redirect subdomain that has the url as parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm wanting to redirect

http://m.example.com/?url=http://www.example.com/directory/page.html

to

http://www.example.com/directory/page.html (always the value of 'url=')

The are mobile versions of my site that I want to serve on my main site. Right now the search results contain my mobile pages. Until the main, responsive pages are crawled I want to force them to be viewed.

Comment: That initial URL is invalid. The value (the URL) would have to be url encoded: `http://m.example.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fdirectory%2Fpage.html`. Though probably that invalid URL will work in most cases.

Comment: That is correct, arkascha, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the question your incoming url is invalid. The query parameter (the value) would have to be url encoded like that to be valid: `http://m.example.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fdir‌​ectory%2Fpage.html`. Though probably that invalid URL will work in most cases.

This should do what you are looking for:

```
RewriteMap unescape int:unescape
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)url=http(s?)%3A%2F%2F([^%]+)%2F([^&]+)(&?.*)$
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3/${unescape:%4}?%1%5 [R=301,END]
```

Note that the `RewriteMap` directive can only be used inside the http servers host configuration, *not* in dynamic configuration files. If you need to use such a file (see general note below), you have to split the above into two separate sections:

Inside your http servers (virtual) host configuration:

```
RewriteMap unescape int:unescape
```

Inside your dynamic configuration file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)url=http(s?)%3A%2F%2F([^%]+)%2F([^&]+)(&?.*)$
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3/${unescape:%4}?%1%5 [R=301,END]
```

If you do *not* want any `http GET` parameters to be handed over to the final redirection target, then the above can be simplified:

```
RewriteMap unescape int:unescape
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=http(s?)%3A%2F%2F([^%]+)%2F([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ http%1://%2/${unescape:%3} [R=301,END,QSD]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I implemented this rule but I'm now getting the 'redirected too many times' error. 

Here is an example of an actual url: http://m.thepathoftruth.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thepathoftruth.com%2Ffalse-teachers%2F2696

(the "m" subdomain is currently pointed to a mobile hosted page but I'm going to be adding a CNAME soon to point it to the host server)

I noticed that the url parameter has an unwanted addition, "#2696" which would need to be taken out of the redirect. Any ideas?

Also, thanks for the tip on the host configuration options, I'm going to look into that.

Comment: I also found out I have some situations where a secondary parameter is sent:

http://m.thepathoftruth.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thepathoftruth.com%2F&utm_referrer=#2728

Comment: I modified the pattern slightly to ignore another parameter potentially following the first one. Also I suggest how to prevent the endless redirection by using the `QSD` flag or a workaround.

Comment: I've now added this:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ ${unesc:%1}? [R,NE]

I'm not getting a redirect error but it is redirecting to my home page, not the complete url, and appending the second parameter:

Example:  http://www.thepathoftruth.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thepathoftruth.com%2Ffalse-teachers%2Findex.htm#2696

going to

http://www.thepathoftruth.com/#2696

Comment: I added the `RewriteMap` to declare the `unesc` modifier. Can you please tell what version of the http server you are using?

Comment: Server Version: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1
Server MPM: prefork

When I added the RewriteMap I'm getting the dreaded Internal server config.

Comment: Very strange. Can you please post the _exact_ internal error message you get? Please take a look into your http servers error log file for that.

Comment: www.thepathoftruth.com [Mon Apr 03 11:50:24 2017] [alert] [pid 1866] config.c(2200): [client 66.39.61.108:40233] /usr/www/users/rtanner2/thepathoftruth.com/.htaccess: RewriteMap not allowed here

and I'm getting one other recurring one, but I don't think it's related:

www.thepathoftruth.com [Mon Apr 03 11:50:33 2017] [error] [pid 1866] core.c(3826): [client 216.123.255.242:49759] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

Comment: Ah sure, ok. So you _are_ using dynamic configuration files instead of placing the rules in the http servers host configuration as recommended. In that context you cannot use that mapping approach. May I ask _why_ you use a dynamic configuration file (`.htaccess` style file)?

Comment: Have a try to skip the explicit unescaping and rely on the module itself to make sense if things. I adjusted the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sticking with me on this. The reason I'm using .htaccess is I'm using a caching plugin for Wordpress (W3 Total Cache) that utilizes htaccess for all their rewrites. I'm not sure they give the option to use a config file.

I implemented the adjusted re-write and it seems like it's getting closer:

http://www.thepathoftruth.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thepathoftruth.com%2Fteachings%2Findex.htm&utm_referrer=#2728

now goes to: 

The requested URL /http://www.thepathoftruth.com/teachings/index.htm was not found on this server.

It needs to 301 and remove leading /

Comment: You can still place such rules in the host configuration, you can mix that with dynamic rules as things like wordpress require.

Comment: I made another modification to preserve _other_ query arguments without creating a redirection loop.

Comment: Hmm, no error but still no 301 and it's looking for the URL with a preceding "/"

The requested URL /http://www.thepathoftruth.com/teachings/index.htm was not found on this server.

Comment: Another modification, the result of my local testing, works with http and https likewise.

Comment: My host is not allowing me to edit the virtual host file, even though it's a dedicated server. I've logged a ticket though.

It seems we were getting close without the Rewritemap?

Comment: No, you won't be able to unencode the %2F in `dir‌​ectory%2Fpage.html`. The rest certainly can be done as shown above.

Comment: Ok, good news, my host was able to add the Rewritebase to the file so the redirect is working, with one minor thing left, the "&utm_referrer=#2728" is being appended to the url so the final result is a valid 301 to this:

http://www.thepathoftruth.com/teachings/index.htm?utm_referrer=#2728

Also, when I update my CNAME record and these url's are coming from the subdomain m.thepathoftruth.com instead of www.thepathoftruth.com would there need to be a change?

Comment: You said there are additional `GET` parameters, so I assumed they need to be handed over too. What good should they do otherwise? If you do not want them, then the whole thing can be simplified, certainly. I added a version for that case, though I do not understand the change of requirements.

Comment: I am not really sure if I understand what you refer to with the name resolution detail. Certainly the rules will work on any host they are applied and redirect to any host specified. One question here: this all reads as if you don't even bother to try to understand the rules you copy from here. That is not a good idea...

Comment: Yes, I wasn't clear that although there would be other parameters I wouldn't necessarily need to use them, just consider them in the rewrite. I *think* this one, "&utm_referrer=#????" is the only one I see that needs to just be removed.

Comment: "One question here: this all reads as if you don't even bother to try to understand the rules you copy from here. That is not a good idea"

I am wanting to understand these things, but I found myself in a tight spot with a busy site that was converted overnight and I'm scrambling a bit to clean up things that could have an immediate detrimental effect.  I'm seeing new things in this particular rule and once the dust settles I'd like to look each part over and actually see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Consider this closed. I voted it as the verified answer and suspect that is all that's needed.

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help. Remember to give back to the community here one day and help others with your gained expertise ;-)

Comment: Hi there.. it's me again :-)

Is there a way to strip off the hash and everything after? It doesn't affect the page content but it's just annoying. For example:

This:

http://m.thepathoftruth.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thepathoftruth.com%2Ffalse-teachers%2Findex.htm#2696

becomes this:

http://www.thepathoftruth.com/false-teachers/index.htm#2696

Comment: Sure there is... The trailing `(&?.*)$` in the `RewriteCond` captures everything in the query string from the last `&` onwards, the `%5` in the `RewriteRule` target copies that to the target URL. So if you modify the condition such that any _potential_ hash character along with its argument gets captured separately you can chose to _not_ copy it to the target URL. You should be able to add such a detail yourself by now... Otherwise please post a separate question and feel free to add me with an `@` in a short comment.